# Node js : TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'existsSync'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to upload file and I am using node js in server(version : [nodemon] v1.0.1). The following code worked before 4 months after that I did n't check it and yesterday I run it again. But it is not working and I got `"TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'existsSync'"` error in console. Following is my code

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = module.exports = express();
var calenderid;
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter, https = require('https'), http = require('http'), querystring = require('querystring'), url = require('url');
var path2;
app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.compress());
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({
        secret : 'foobar'
    }));
    app.use(express.bodyParser({
        uploadDir : __dirname + '/uploads'
    }));
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

});


var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    port : '3306',
    database : 'db',
    user : 'root',
    password : '',
});

connection.connect();
var fs = require('fs');
app.post('/file-upload/:id', function(req, res) {
    var tble = "image";
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log("req.files.files" + JSON.stringify(req.files),
            req.files.files.length);
    var tmp_path = req.files.files[0].path;
    console.log("hiii temp path" + tmp_path, typeof tmp_path);
    // var firstIdx =0
    var lastidx = tmp_path.lastIndexOf("/");
    var path = tmp_path.substring(0, lastidx);
    console.log("target path sub" + lastidx, tmp_path);
    // var target_path = path+"\"+req.files.files[0].name;
    var dirExists = fs.existsSync(__dirname + "/uploads/" + id);

    console.log(dirExists);
    if (!dirExists) {

        fs.mkdirSync(__dirname + "/uploads/" + id);
        target_path = path + "/" + id + "/" + req.files.files[0].name;
    } else {
        target_path = path + "/" + id + "/" + req.files.files[0].name;
    }
    console.log("hiii target_path" + target_path);
    fs.rename(tmp_path, target_path, function(err) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        // delete the temporary file, so that the explicitly set temporary
        // upload dir does not get filled with unwanted files
        fs.unlink(tmp_path, function() {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            // res.send('File uploaded to: ' + target_path + ' - ' +
            // req.files.files[0].size + ' bytes'+req.files.files.length);
            // queryurl = 'SELECT * FROM ' +tble + ' WHERE ' + id;
            queryurl = 'SELECT * FROM ' + tble + ' WHERE image=' + '"'
                    + req.files.files[0].name + '"' + ' AND branch=' + '"' + id
                    + '"';
            connection.query(queryurl, function(err, result, fields) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result) + "result.image");
                if (result.length == 0) {
                    console.log("in if !result");
                    connection.query('INSERT INTO ' + tble + '(' + 'branch'
                            + ',' + 'image' + ')' + 'VALUES' + '(' + '"' + id
                            + '"' + ',' + '"' + req.files.files[0].name + '"'
                            + ")", function(err, result, fields) {
                        if (err)
                            throw err;
                        else {

                            res.send('File uploaded to: ' + target_path + ' - '
                                    + req.files.files[0].size + ' bytes'
                                    + req.files.files.length);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log("in else !result");
                    res.send("duplicate");

                }
            });

        });
    });

});
```

Following is the error that I got from console.

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'existsSync'
    at /var/www/jts-web/WebContent/app.js:95:20
    at callbacks (/var/www/web/WebContent/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:165:11)
    at param (/var/www/web/WebContent/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:139:11)
    at param (/var/www/web/WebContent/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:136:11)
    at pass (/var/www/web/WebContent/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:146:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/var/www/web/WebContent/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:173:5)
    at Object.router [as handle] (/var/www/web/WebContent/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
    at next (/var/www/web/WebContent/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    at Object.methodOverride [as handle] (/var/www/web/WebContent/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/methodOverride.js:37:5)
    at next (/var/www/web/WebContent/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
```

In one site somebody told it will overcome after upgrading node js. But this code was working fine. It is not good if I need to upgrade for each change.

Comment: please show the code where you define `fs`. it should be `var fs = require('fs').`

Comment: Where you declared fs ?

Comment: You shouldn't use `sync` methods in server code.

Comment: @ChristianFritz yes I defined var fs = require('fs') in top of that node js file

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding the following code

```
fs.existsSync = require('path').existsSync;
```

above

```
var dirExists = fs.existsSync(__dirname + "/uploads/" + id);
```

[I got solution from this site](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3005)

Answer (score 5):

As a side note, as I encountered somewhat *similar* issue but on different scenario.

I tried to run grunt for bootstrap.
Here is the error I got:

```
 /home/user/gbootstrap/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/file.js:374
   return fs.existsSync(filepath);
             ^
 TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'existsSync'
     at Object.exists (/home/user/gbootstrap/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/file.js:374:13)
     at Task.init (/home/user/gbootstrap/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:423:31)
     at Object.initTasks (/home/user/gbootstrap/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/help.js:90:14)
     at /home/user/gbootstrap/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/help.js:49:55
     at Array.forEach (native)
     at Object.display (/home/user/gbootstrap/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/help.js:49:17)
     at Object.tasks (/home/user/gbootstrap/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:101:10)
     at Object.cli (/home/user/gbootstrap/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/cli.js:38:9)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/gnode-v0.10.26-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt:45:20)
     at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
```

I found the root cause was due to i am using the default debian nodejs package (version 0.6.19) from repository.

Solution:
1. remove the nodejs:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
```

2. download the binary from http://nodejs.org/download/
3. use the correct node and npm from the bin folder. Then it runs...

credit to this post:
https://github.com/Crisu83/yii-app/issues/13

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you load the core `fs` module at the top of this file like `var fs = require("fs");`. Other that that, `existsSync` should be there.

Side note: You can't use synchronous IO calls in a network server such as this. It completely destroys node's concurrency model at a basic and fundamental level. Use the async versions. You're already using some of them, just use async version exclusively and you'll be noding correctly.

Comment: Post a full snippet. This is a very very basic error. Something basic is wrong but we can't help you if you paste partial snippets and the problem lies outside of the "interesting" part of the code. Doing `require("fs").existsSync` works fine in a node repl.

Comment: Something truly basic is whack here. See how the stack trace line and column number don't match up to your snippet? Are you even looking in the right file? Line 95 of your snippet contains only a curly brace. Pause. Reset your mind. Go slow. This is an easy one if you stick to your basics but you are doing something silly like looking in the wrong directory or wrong file entirely.

Comment: Stack traces don't lie. I'm out. Good luck.